# Adding segmentation into groups using percentiles

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The question is the following - I have a table with data personalized for each user, looking like this:

| user_id | ltv | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6759183 | 2325262 | 160531 |
| 53563 | 4622344 | 150093 |
| 2473425 | 6846844 | 52398 |
| 575799 | 112356 | 123568 |
| 16343 | 457680 | 19468 |
| 67953 | 246757 | 34597 |
| 768453 | 1760055 | 140398 |
| 3563573 | 5005498 | 20395 |

It is necessary to add segmentation into 4 buckets (by percentiles) for each characteristic field in order to understand which bucket will contain users for each characteristic.

The output should look like this:

| user_id | ltv | score | ltv_backet | score_backet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6759183 | 2325262 | 160531 | 3 | 4 |
| 53563 | 4622344 | 150093 | 3 | 4 |
| 2473425 | 6846844 | 52398 | 4 | 1 |
| 575799 | 112356 | 123568 | 1 | 3 |
| 16343 | 457680 | 19468 | 2 | 1 |
| 67953 | 246757 | 34597 | 1 | 2 |
| 768453 | 1760055 | 140398 | 4 | 3 |
| 3563573 | 5005498 | 20395 | 4 | 1 |

I tried to do segmentation through the following request

```
select user_id, user_score, ltv_rub,
    case
    when user_score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_score) over(partition by user_id) then 1
    when user_score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_score) over(partition by user_id) then 2
    when user_score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_score) over(partition by user_id) then 3
    when user_score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_score) over(partition by user_id) then 4
    end as score_backet,
    case
    when ltv_rub <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv_rub) over(partition by user_id) then 1
    when ltv_rub <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv_rub) over(partition by user_id) then 2
    when ltv_rub <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv_rub) over(partition by user_id) then 3
    when ltv_rub <= PERCENTILE_CONT(1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv_rub) over(partition by user_id) then 4
    end as ltv_backet
    from public.users_rating
```

but at the output the data that should be segmented into different groups is filled with ones for every records in table. Please tell me where am I wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to using the `PARTITION BY user_id` clause in your `OVER` clause. Partitioning by `user_id` means that each row is treated as a separate partition, so the percentile calculation is being done within each individual user, rather than across all users as you intended.

To segment the data into buckets based on percentiles across all users, you should remove the `PARTITION BY user_id` clause. Here's the corrected query:

```sql
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    ltv, 
    score, 
    CASE
        WHEN score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score) OVER() THEN 1
        WHEN score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score) OVER() THEN 2
        WHEN score <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY score) OVER() THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END AS score_bucket,
    CASE
        WHEN ltv <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv) OVER() THEN 1
        WHEN ltv <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv) OVER() THEN 2
        WHEN ltv <= PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ltv) OVER() THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END AS ltv_bucket
FROM 
    public.users_rating;
```

In this corrected query, we're not partitioning by `user_id`, so the percentile calculation is done across all users. This should segment the data into buckets based on percentiles correctly. Hope it's help.